# Year wrong on Epoch time conversion

Tags: python, epoch

I'm trying to convert epoch time using Python. However, the year always seems to be wrong. In the below example, it should be 2014.

```
import time
timestamp = time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", 
                    time.localtime(1415219530834))
```

What am I doing wrong?

I get this result:

```
Sat, 09 Jul 46816 16:20:34 +0000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing time in milliseconds, but it should be in seconds. Divide it by 1000

```
import time
timestamp = time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", 
                    time.localtime(1415219530))
```

result:

`'Wed, 05 Nov 2014 15:32:10 +0000'`

Answer (score 1):

You've passed a timestamp in milliseconds, but `localtime` expects a value in seconds.

```
time.localtime(1415219530834 / 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this also

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(your time in epoch/1000)
```

Convert time in epoch

```
int(yourtime.strftime("%s"))*1000
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the Epoch in Milliseconds in Python. You need to get it in seconds for it to work correctly.

Something like

```
import time
mytime = 1415219530834
seconds = int(mytime/1000)
timestamp = time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000",time.localtime(seconds))
```